# "more" like command in R console

Tags: r, rstudio

Is there any command in R console which behaves same as "more" command in Linux?
Consider this

```
>x=list(seq(100000), seq(100000))
>x
```

It displays everything at one go and shows message at the end "reached getOption("max.print")". Scrolling back to top doesn't show me the first values. I need a command like more(x) which will show more and more by pressing space bar.

Comment: I'm not aware of such a function and have never missed it because I don't feel the need to look at each element of large objects. However, you could implement that yourself.

Answer (score 6):

Would `?page` do the trick? e.g., `page(list(a = rnorm(1000), b=rnorm(1000)))`

Comment: Nice answer. There is also the option of `method="print"`, which maybe handy.